# How to get only IP address from nmblookup for use in Bash script?

Tags: samba, string-manipulation

If I do:

```
nmblookup myServerName
```

I get:

```
192.168.6.106 myservername<00>
```

Since I want to use the IP returned from `nmblookup myServerName` in a Bash script, I'd like to know the best way to return only the IP, not the `myservername<00>` part of the string. I've looked at [the nmblookup documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/nmblookup.1.html), but I cannot find an option that would help me.

Comment: To be more precise: `nmblookup server | awk '/^[0-9]+/ {print $1}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to add some stricter checks including sanity-checking, as nmblookup might fail, if myServerName is down:

```
RES=$(nmblookup myServerName 2>/dev/null)
if test "$?" != "0"; then
  echo "nmblookup failed"
  # Do something
  exit 10
fi

IP1=$(echo "$RES" | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)\..*/\1/')
IP1=$(printf '%d' "$IP1" 2>/dev/null)
test -z "$IP1" && IP1=256

IP2=$(echo "$RES" | sed "s/^$IP1\\.\\([0-9]*\\)\\..*/\\1/")
IP2=$(printf '%d' "$IP2" 2>/dev/null)
test -z "$IP2" && IP2=256

IP3=$(echo "$RES" | sed "s/^$IP1\\.$IP2\\.\\([0-9]*\\)\\..*/\\1/")
IP3=$(printf '%d' "$IP3" 2>/dev/null)
test -z "$IP3" && IP3=256

IP4=$(echo "$RES" | sed "s/^$IP1\\.$IP2\\.$IP3\\.\\([0-9]*\\).*/\\1/")
IP4=$(printf '%d' "$IP4" 2>/dev/null)
test -z "$IP4" && IP4=256

OK=1
test $IP1 -gt 255 && OK=0
test $IP2 -gt 255 && OK=0
test $IP3 -gt 255 && OK=0
test $IP4 -gt 255 && OK=0
if test "$OK" != "1"; then
  echo "nmblookup talking garbage"
  # Do something
  exit 11
fi
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! That was my next hurtle (as I'm still learning Bash). Your answer is great. Now to read up on ```test```! Seems handy and complex. http://ss64.com/bash/test.html